# What is the syntax for a sorted XPath query on atomic values?

Tags: xpath, saxon

I am trying to execute the following select in my Java code:

```
// initialized earlier
private XdmNode xmlDocument;
private XPathCompiler xPath;

// ... the code that's a problem:

XPathExecutable exec = xPath.compile("sort(distinct-values(/root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets/element/associatedAttributes/element[(value != '') and (dataParamName != 'modelNomenclature')]/name), (), function($node) { $node/displaySeq })");
XPathSelector selector = exec.load();
selector.setContextItem(xmlDocument);
selector.evaluate();
```

The call to evaluate() throws the exception:

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(); the supplied value u"Model Name" is an atomic value
```

What is wrong with the query? I know distinct-values() returns atomic values, but why is there a problem sorting those? Is it that $node makes no sense to sort atomic values? But the select (without the sort) is:

```
/root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets/element/associatedAttributes/element[(value != '') and (dataParamName != 'modelNomenclature')]/name
```

And there is at /root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets/element/associatedAttributes:

```
    <associatedAttributes>
      <element>
        <uom>N/A</uom>
        <name>Model Name</name>
        <dataParamName>modelName</dataParamName>
        <seq />
        <value>A17-230P1A</value>
        <displayLevel>0</displayLevel>
        <displaySeq>5</displaySeq>
        <displayLevelTitle />
        <displayName>Model Name</displayName>
        <dataGroup />
      </element>
```

So it seems logical (to me) as it's "...[...]/name" that it can sort on displaySeq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "/" operator requires a node (not an atomic value) on the LHS (as the error message says).

You're trying, I think, to eliminate `element` elements as duplicates if they have the same `name` child, and then to sort them by the value of `displaySeq`. Unfortunately `distinct-values()` only retains the (atomic) values, it loses knowledge of the nodes from which these values were derived. (And in principle at least, two elements with the same `name` can have different values for `displaySeq`, so it's not clear which one you want to retain.

Ideally you would use XSLT or XQuery grouping for this, rather than distinct-values. If you have to use XPath, you could consider creating a map to do the deduplication:

```
let $index := map:merge(/root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets
           /element/associatedAttributes/element[
             (value != '') and (dataParamName != 'modelNomenclature')
           ]!map{displaySeq : .}/name)
 return sort(map:for-each($index, function($k, $v){$v}), 
             (), function($node) { $node/displaySeq })
```

Not tested.

Comment: The LHS is the $node/displaySeq part (the sorting node) correct? And in that, displaySeq  is an atomic value? If so, what is u"Model Name" referencing because the values for displaySeq are numbers (0, 1, 2) used as the sort order.

Comment: @DavidThielen, your `distinct-values` gives you a sequence of string values (like "Model Name") and you can't use `/` on a string or any other atomic value.

Comment: Oh right - I wasn't thinking it through. As always, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
distinct-values(sort(/root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets/element/associatedAttributes/element[(value != '') and (dataParamName != 'modelNomenclature')], (), function($node) { $node/displaySeq })!name)
```

gives you the right result, it sorts the `element` elements by the `displaySeq`, than selects the `name` child elements and computes the distinct ones.

You could also write it as

```
(/root/data/hasTransaction/element/hasAssets/element/associatedAttributes/element[(value != '') and (dataParamName != 'modelNomenclature')] => sort((), function($node) { $node/displaySeq })) ! name => distinct-values()
```

Comment: I will suggest that - it might give them what they need. Thanks